# Python Requests' detected as bot?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

Currently doing research on the process of a particular API.

I have been able to reproduce API calls using Postman, however I cannot get them to reproduce using Python Requests, or another library.

I receive an unknown error was attempting to make an API call. I have already changed my user agent. Is it possible that they can see that I am using requests? What else can I do?

Comment: make sure you include all the headers that's being sent by the browser when making the api call, like `cookie`, `user-agent` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use proxies with help of requests module in python. Either use free proxies or you can buy the shared proxies.

```
proxy_obj = {
            'http': 'http://proxy1.com',
            'https': 'https://proxy1.com',
            }
req = requests.get(image_url, proxies=proxy_obj)
```